# Do magnets lose their magnetism/force when they attract/repel each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

So yea, if two magnets attract/repel multiple times(A LOT) will they lose their magnetism? If they don't break during the whole process?

Comment: I don't know the material well enough to answer but check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercivity and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/magperm.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can. Here is a nice article about preventing that:

[Care & Feeding of your magnet](http://www.coolmagnetman.com/magcare.htm)